# Want to get the same deck to each client instead of a random one in nodejs/socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, blackjack

I am trying to build a simple blackjack game with socket.io,node and react but the problem is that after creating a room with 2 clients + dealer,each client gets different cards at the start of the game.

Any way to get the deck to build only once and then send the same on to the clients?

This is the server code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const buildDeck = require('./helpers/buildDeck');

require('dotenv').config();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

let deck;
let size;
let users = ['dealer'];
let playCards = [];

app.use(cors());

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} has been connected`);

    socket.on('joinRoom', (data) => {
        size = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(data.room)?.size;
        if (size > 1) {
            io.to(socket.id).emit('reject');
            socket.disconnect();
        } else {
            socket.join(data.room);
            users.push(data.user);
            console.log(users);
        }
    });

    socket.on('checkPlayers', (data) => {
        size = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(data.room)?.size;
        if (size === 2) {
            io.to(socket.id).emit('joinedRoom', size);
            deck = buildDeck();
        }
        socket.to(data.room).emit('joinedRoom', size);
    });

    socket.on('initialize', (room) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            playCards[i] = {
                user: users[i],
                cards: [deck.pop(), deck.pop()],
            };
        }
        console.log(playCards);
        socket.to(room).emit('initialize', { deck, playCards });
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: @PeterJames I want my server to build the deck and shuffle only once.As in not be affected by the number of clients.At this point though I am getting a different deck for each client.

Comment: Move the deck initialisation logic _out_ of the event handlers

Comment: @Phil It was initially at top,but still ran 2 times instead of once.

Comment: @PeterJames That was a godsend.Thanks.Can you explain please why does deck.pop lead to building the deck and randomizing it again?